# Grouped items in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm playing a little with XAML and Windows Store app.
I'm having a listview which is a phonebook, where all contacts are shown by name now.

Now, what I want to change is, to group them by the first letter in the name, so all contacts starting with 'A' is listed below a header named A, and so on.

Anyone that could help me out on this? What is the best way to do this, when I use a DataContext Binding to a source of a json file, which I again use as ItemSource="{Binding}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CollectionViewSource and IsSourceGrouped

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209833